# Выдает ошибку при установке pyinstaller

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame, pyinstaller

**ЧТО Я ПРОБОВАЛ**

На этом сайте я прочитал о похожих проблемах людей и не смог решить свою.
мне выдавало такую ошибку:

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе: 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_ctypes-0.2.0.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Я опускал версию pip до 18.1, пытался поменять название папки C\users\Миша(У меня не получилось) и я хотел переустанавливать сам Python, но я незнаю как и даже уже нехочиться. Также включать режим админа и запускал консоль от имени последнего. Тк я новичек прошу писать подробно(если это конечно возможно)

Зарание спасибо!

Comment: Удалить как и любую программу через установку и удаление в python тут ничего нового. А лучше не ставьте пакеты в основной python. Используйте виртуальное окружение (да надо погуглить и чуть разобраться) но это позволит избежать пакетной помойки. https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 0):

выполните ту же команду, используя '--user'